# use of unresolved identifier 'terminator'， apple's documentation is wrong?

Tags: swift

Can anybody figure it out? Plz see the picture below
[image]

In apple's api:https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/reversedcollection/1786680-reversed

you can see he also uses '='
 [image]

Comment: It should be `terminator: ""`

Comment: You can see the link above, apple uses "="

Comment: The Apple example is wrong :)

Comment: Why downvote? This question/answer saved my day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
print(char, terminator: "")
```

Found here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/1541053-print

Comment: Think so, check out my link .. If it's works, mark this answer as solution :)